# Average energy of a damped-forced harmonic oscillator during a period t

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

In my textbook, it's  stated without proving the following identity for a classical damped-forced harmonic oscillator:

$$
\bar{E}^t = \bar{T}^t + \bar{V}^t = 2 \bar{T}^t \, ,
$$

which states that its average energy in a period of time $t$ is equal to twice its kinetic energy $T$. I have seen this identity for a classical harmonic oscillator without damping and forcing. Can you see why the identity remains?